# How did temple priests and visitors go about relieving themselves without desecrating the sanctity of the Beit Hamikdash?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, bathroom

Judaism has very strict rules around human waste and separating God from such things. *You may not even speak God's names within a restroom.*

This leads to my question regarding the temple priesthood and how they handled issues of the human condition. In the event they had to use the restroom, did they quite literally have to come down from the mount to a specified area away from the temple or did they have a special location on or at the edge of the mount which allowed them to use restroom facilities?

This question may sound odd but I'm genuinely curious as to how such issues were handled.

Comment: "they quite literally have to come down from the mount to a specified area away from the temple" I'm not sure why this would be shocking. Baseball players don't just relieve themseleves in the middle of the field; they leave the field and go out to a locker room where there are specified areas for such activities.

Comment: See the first mishna in tractate Tamid

Comment: Wasn't writing in a "this is shocking" way. Just presenting the possible situation.